# mysql datetime between

Tags: mysql

Есть табличка которая содержит поле datetime. Требуется выбрать данные из таблицы которые попадают под определённое ВРЕМЯ. Как можно сделать подобный запрос? Что то в духе SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '08:00' AND '23:00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию [TIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time), которая выделяет из DATETIME компоненту времени.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE TIME(`date`) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '23:00'
```